# How to create the right output of an excel file from xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, excel

I've been trying to make an excel file from an `xml`.
This is the `php` code that I get from other stackoverflow answer and I try to use it:

```
function createexcel() {
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xlsx");// put your file name here
        $url = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Ready/xml_product_feed.xml'; // xml file location with file name
        if (file_exists($url)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        echo 'Thumbnail'."\t".'Product Name'."\t".'Price'."\t".'Stock'."\t".'Description'."\t\n";
        foreach($xml->xpath("//item") as $item)
        {
          $extraData = $item->children('g',true);
          echo $extraData->thumbnail_url."\t".$extraData->productname."\t".$extraData->price."\t".$extraData->avail."\t".$extraData->productdescription."\t"."\t\n";
        }
      }
    }
```

And this is the `xml` file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <item id="1234">
    <g:productname>Blue Shirt</g:productname>
    <g:productdescription>Height : 70cm 
Width : 60 cm 
Material : cotton</g:productdescription>
    <g:price>12</g:price>
    <g:avail>20</g:avail>
    <g:thumbnail_url>http://matchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/plain-blue-shirt-front-and-back-72hi3bcb.jpg</g:thumbnail_url>
  </item>
```

It successfully downloaded the excel file, but the thing is, the value of the excel file in the Description column is not put in one column.
This is the screen shoot of it:

[image: Screen shoot of the excel file]

I want to make the Description value put in one column. Really need help here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all when I saved your XML, it was not valid for me.

So I made changes in that for me, If your XML working fine for you don't use my XML

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <item id="1234">
    <productname>Blue Shirt</productname>
    <productdescription>Height : 70cm Width : 60 cm Material : cotton</productdescription>
    <price>12</price>
    <avail>20</avail>
    <thumbnail_url>http://matchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/plain-blue-shirt-front-and-back-72hi3bcb.jpg</thumbnail_url>
  </item>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    createexcel();
    function createexcel() {
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls");// put your file name here
        $url = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/new/xml_file.xml'; // xml file location with file name
        if (file_exists($url)) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
            echo 'Thumbnail'."\t".'Product Name'."\t".'Price'."\t".'Stock'."\t".'Description'."\t\n";
            foreach($xml->xpath("//item") as $item)
            echo $item->thumbnail_url."\t".$item->productname."\t".$item->price."\t".$item->avail."\t".$item->productdescription."\t"."\t\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

You just need to change in you XML for your problem. Please do the following changes

**Your XML**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <item id="1234">
        <g:productname>Blue Shirt</g:productname>
        <g:productdescription>Height : 70cm 
    Width : 60 cm 
    Material : cotton</g:productdescription>
        <g:price>12</g:price>
        <g:avail>20</g:avail>
        <g:thumbnail_url>http://matchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/plain-blue-shirt-front-and-back-72hi3bcb.jpg</g:thumbnail_url>
      </item>
```

**New XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <item id="1234">
        <productname>Blue Shirt</productname>
        <productdescription>Height : 70cm Width : 60 cm Material : cotton</productdescription>//Change Here
        <price>12</price>
        <avail>20</avail>
        <thumbnail_url>http://matchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/plain-blue-shirt-front-and-back-72hi3bcb.jpg</thumbnail_url>
    </item>
```